# Existe um oposto para `contains`?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma lista:

```
List<int> lista1 = new List<int>();
lista1.Add(1);
lista1.Add(2);
lista1.Add(3);

List<int> lista2 = new List<int>();
lista2.Add(1);
lista2.Add(2);
```

Para obter da `lista1` os elementos que existem também na `lista2` basta usar:

```
var resultado = lista1.Where(li => lista2.Contains(li)).ToList();
```

Assim o resultado obtido é: `{ 1 , 2 }`.

Até aí tudo bem, mas e se eu quisesse obter da `lista1` os elementos que **não** estão na `lista2`?

No caso o resultado deveria ser `{ 3 }`.

É possível resolver isso em apenas uma linha?

Estou usando Entity Framework.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Você está procurando pelo [`Except()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

```
var resultado = lista1.Except(lista2).ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Except.cs).

Comment: Bem mais bonito essa maneira! Mas não funciona dentro do Where, tive que usar da seguinte forma: `var resultado = lista1.Except(lista2).ToList();`. Corrige aí que eu aceito a sua como solução...

Comment: É verdade, eu fui fazer direto no seu exemplo, eu fui testar agora e não deu :) Corrigido. Alias, eu tenho dúvidas se o seu usando `Contains()` é a forma correta de usar, apesar de possível.

Comment: Só uma nota: `Except` é uma [operacaçao de conjuntos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) e, portanto, elimina duplicados. Se `lista1` contiver `{1,2,3,3}` o resultado vai ser apenas `{3}`.

Answer (score 21):

Você pode fazer:

```
var resultado = lista1.Where(li => !lista2.Contains(li)).ToList();
```

Comment: Como não pensei nisso antes?! rsrsrs... Muito obrigado! 100% resolvido.